# Why is my sidebar hiding everytime after second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sidebar

The sidebar is hidden and it will fadeIn once I have submitted the correct pin. But when I click any option in the sidebar more than once it is hiding! Why?

```
var pin = 1234; 

$("#confirm_pin").click(function () {
    var pin = document.getElementById("Pin").value;

    if (pin == 1234) {
        alert("You have now acesss!");

        $(".management").hide();
        $(".management_sidebar").fadeIn();

    } else {
        alert("Please, enter the correct pin");
    }
});

    $(".option_management").on("click", function () {

            $(".page_holder_management").children().hide();

            var option = $.trim($(this).text());
            var find_click_object = $(this).attr("id");


            if (option == "Home page") {
                $("div.page_holder_management > div:nth-child(1)").fadeIn();
            } else {
                alert("false");
            }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="management_sidebar" style="display:none;"> 
    <div class="header_management_sidebar"> 
        <p style="position:absolute; margin:10px; font-weight:bold;">  Site administration  </p> 
    </div>
    <div id="management_content" STYLE="margin:20px; color:black;">
        <div class="box_management"> 
            <div class="option_management" id="1">Home page</div>
            <div class="option_management" id="2">Table page</div>
            <div class="option_management"> test </div>
            <div class="option_management"> test </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="page_holder_management">

    <div class="management_homePage" style="display:none;"> 
        <div class="header_management_homePage"> 
                <p style="position:absolute; margin:10px; color:black; font-weight:bold;">  Change home page  </p> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="management_tablePage" style="display:none;"> 
        <div class="header_management_homePage"> 
                <p style="position:absolute; margin:10px; color:black; font-weight:bold;">  Change table page  </p> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

In the html code I made pages that should fadeIn when I click on any option in the sidebar and it should fadeOut when i click another option with another page should fadeIn!

Please tell me where I am doing wrong?

PLease check this http://kapten.mzzhost.com/test/System_management.php to test my problem! The pin is: 1234

Comment: What is `.management` that you are hiding?

Comment: I was asking for a pin in the beginning and when I have submitted correct pin. The pin div will hide, which is .management

Comment: And why are you `fadeIn` the sidebar on option click?

Comment: Is there any more JS than this?

Comment: Please create a jsbin or jsfiddle with this! Thanks!

Comment: You also have set your href to System management, accept for your table button that sends you to a none existing page :)

Answer (score 0):

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5G47W/1/), you should make html and js relations simpler. I used data attributes there and if i understand correctly, this is what you want

```
 var pin = 1234; 

$("#confirm_pin").click(function () {
var pin = document.getElementById("Pin").value;

if (pin == 1234) {
    alert("You have now acesss!");

    $(".management").hide();
    $(".management_sidebar").fadeIn();

 } else {
     alert("Please, enter the correct pin");
 }
});

$(".option_management").on("click", function () {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('.contents').hide();
    $('.contents.' + target).fadeIn();        
});
```

html changes with data attribute

```
 <div class="option_management" data-target="management_homePage" id="1">Home page</div>
 <div class="option_management" data-target="management_tablePage" id="2">Table page</div>
```

Comment: What exactly was wrong with my code? I never coded to hide sidebar and why does it hiding after two clicks?

Comment: Can't say, it was not hiding in my test. Maybe there's another div with background on top? maybe it's a browser specific issue? in any way, you should avoid the if ... then with selected strings, it will get messy at some point for sure.

Comment: Problem solved! I had it in position absolute, so the content was over the sidebar!

Comment: Great, that's what I meant by saying there's another div with background on top....

Comment: $('.contents.' + target).fadeIn(); is this only working if it is class or will it work with Id attribute?

Comment: It should work with an id, just remember: if the element has id #a AND class .b, you make reference to it by #a.b (no space). Space means nested element. Also, ids cant exist twice in the document.